# Question about a homomorphism of a cyclic extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I came across the following problem, and I'm unsure about how to prove a specific part regarding a particular homomorphism of a cyclic extension of a field.  Here's the problem:

Let $K_{/F}$ be a cyclic extension of fields of degree $n$ with $\text{Gal}(K_{/F}) = \langle \sigma \rangle$.  Prove the following:

a) If $f(X) =a_m X^m + a_{m-1}X^{m-1} + \dots + a_0 \in F[X] $, define the map $f(\sigma): K \longrightarrow K$ by $b \mapsto a_m \sigma^m(b) + a_{m-1} \sigma^{m-1}(b) + \dots + a_0$ (where $\sigma^i$ denotes $\sigma$ composed with itself $i$ times).  Prove $f(\sigma)$ is an $F$ module homomorphism.

b) Prove if $f(\sigma) \equiv 0$, and $\deg(f) < n$, then $f \equiv 0$.

c) Prove there exists $b \in K$ such that $\{b,\sigma(b),\dots,\sigma^{n-1}(b)\}$ is basis of $K$ over $F$.

I have two questions about this problem.

1. I don't get how $f(\sigma)$ is an $F$ module homomorphism if $a_0 \neq 0$.  We require $f(\sigma)(0) = 0$, but $f(\sigma)(0) = a_m \sigma^{m}(0) + \dots + a_0 = a_0 = 0$ since $\sigma(0)=0$.
2. I don't get how to prove part b without using part c.  Part b is immediate if part c is true, and so I tried to figure out a way to prove c without using b, but it's clear to me from the problem that part b is there to establish some sort of linear independence argument for part c to hold.

Here's my work for part b (not using part c):  Suppose for contradiction that $f \not\equiv 0$ (so there exists $\alpha \in K$ with $f(\alpha) \neq 0$).  Then not all of the coefficients on $f$ are $0$. I know that for the $\alpha$ such that $f(\alpha) \neq 0$, we also get that $f(\sigma)(\alpha) = 0$, and if $Y = \{\beta_1,\beta_2,\dots\beta_n\}$ is a basis of $K$ over $F$,  expanding out $f(\sigma)(\alpha)$ gives you something like: $$f(\sigma)(\alpha) = \sum_{k=0}^m \sum_{i=1}^n a_k t_{i,k} \beta_i = 0$$ where $\sigma^j(\alpha) = \sum_{i=1}^n t_{i,j}\beta_i$ for each $1 \leq j \leq m$ ($t_{i,j} \in F$). Since $Y$ is a basis you get $a_{k}t_{i,k} = 0$ for all $i$. This looks promising since not all the coefficients on $f$ are $0$, so it looks like it might be a non-trivial LC of the elements of $Y$ equating to $0$, which is a contradiction.  However, this somehow depends on $\deg(f) =m < n$, and the problem i see here is that it may be possible that $a_kt_{i,k} = 0$ for all $i$, but this doesn't imply that $t_{i,k}=0$ for all $i$, since it may be that $a_k=0$ whenever $t_{i,k} \neq 0$ and vice versa.

What do you do from here?

Comment: About the first question: You are supposed to think of $\sigma^0$ as the identity mapping of $K$. In other words,
$$f(\sigma)(b)=\sum_{i=0}^m a_i\sigma^i(b)=a_m\sigma^m(b)+\cdots a_1\sigma(b)+a_0b.$$
Therefore $f(\sigma)(0)=0$ for all $f$.

Comment: Part b is [the linear independence of characters](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/131892/11619). See also [Keith Conrad's on-line document for a polished presentation](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/linearchar.pdf)

Comment: The first question seems to arise from a misunderstanding of what an $F$-module homomorphism is. An $F$-module homomorphism is a homomorphism between $F$-modules that is compatible with the action of the field $F$. In this case, you have the $F$-modules $K$ and $K$, and you want to show that $f(\sigma): K \to K$ is an $F$-module homomorphism. We need to show two things:
a) $f(\sigma)(u+v) = f(\sigma)(u) + f(\sigma)(v)$ for all $u, v \in K$.
b) $f(\sigma)(c\cdot u) = c\cdot f(\sigma)(u)$ for all $c \in F$ and $u \in K$.

Comment: Part c follows from part b. One way is to view $K$ as an $F[X]$-module with $X$ acting via $\sigma$. $F[X]$ is a PID, so $K$ is a direct sum of cyclic modules. Part b then implies that no polynomial of degree $<n$ can annihilate all of $K$. Hence (think: invariant factors) $K$ is a cyclic module. If $b$ is a generator of $K$ as an $F[X]$-module, then $b$ can play the role in part c.

Comment: I have given a bit more detailed argument about a cyclic Galois extension having a normal basis (i.e. part c) in the case of finite fields [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/53316/11619). In the case of finite fields part b is a lot easier. But the passage from b to c is the same, so I include the link.

Comment: I'm not inclined to compile an answer as this is all pretty standard field theory. Sorry. I don't know how to best deal with the situation, bounty and all :-(

Comment: See also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/922006/11619)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parts of my answer are hidden to encourage you to try it yourself first.
You can click on those hidden blocks to reveal them.

---

###### Part (a)

In your statement, the map $f(\sigma)(b)$ is defined as
$$
f(\sigma)(b)=a_m\sigma^m(b)+\cdots+a_1\sigma(0)+a_0,
$$
but actually it should be
$$
f(\sigma)(b)=a_m\sigma^m(b)+\cdots+a_1\sigma(b)+a_0\color{red}{\sigma^{0}(b)},
$$
where $\sigma^0$ is the identity map, so $\sigma^0(x)=x$ for any $x\in K$,
and in particular $\sigma^0(0)=0$.
Then we have $f(\sigma)(0)=0$, as expected.

An actual proof should not be difficult now:

> Since $F$ is a field, an $F$-module homomorphism is simply an $F$-linear map.
>  For all $c\in F$ and all $v,w\in K$,
>  $$\begin{align*}f(\sigma)(cv+w) &= \sum_{i=0}^m a_i\sigma^i(cv+w) \\&= \sum_{i=0}^m a_i (c\cdot \sigma^i(v) + \sigma^i(w)) \tag{$\sigma\in\text{Gal}(K/F)$} \\&= \sum_{i=0}^m ca_i\sigma^i(v) + \sum_{i=0}^m a_i\sigma^i(w) \\&= c\cdot f(\sigma)(v) + f(\sigma)(w).\end{align*}$$
>  This shows that $f(\sigma)$ is an $F$-linear map.

###### Part (b)

It suffices to show that $\{\text{id},\sigma,\dots,\sigma^{n-1}\}$ is $F$-linearly independent.
We can proceed by induction on $n$.

Hint:

> Use the fact that $\sigma\neq \sigma^{n-1}$ to
>  find an element $x_0\in K$ such that $\sigma(x_0)\neq \sigma^{n-1}(x_0)$.
>  Plug in $x_0x$ into the equation and try to cancel out $\sigma^{n-1}(x)$ term.

Solution:

> This is trivial for $n=1$.
>  For $n>1$, assume that $\{\text{id},\sigma,\dots,\sigma^{n-2}\}$ is linearly independent.
>  Suppose
>  $$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a_i \sigma^i(x)=0$$
>  for all $x\in K$.
>  Now, there exists $x_0\in K$ such that $\sigma(x_0)\neq \sigma^{n-1}(x_0)$.
>  We have two equations, for all $x\in K$:
>  $$\begin{align*}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a_i \sigma^i(x_0)\sigma^i(x) &=0 \tag{Plug in $x_0x$}\\\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a_i \sigma^{n-1}(x_0)\sigma^i(x) &= 0 \tag{Multiply by $\sigma^{n-1}(x_0)$}\end{align*}$$
>  By a substraction, we have
>  $$\begin{align*}\sum_{i=0}^{n-2} a_i (\sigma^{n-1}(x_0)-\sigma^i(x_0))\sigma^i(x) &=0\end{align*}$$
>  for all $x\in K$.
>  By the linear independence of $\{\text{id},\dots,\sigma^{n-2}\}$
>  and the fact that $\sigma^{n-1}(x_0)-\sigma^i(x_0)\neq 0$,
>  we have $a_i=0$ for all $1\le i\le n-2$,
>  which implies $a_{n-1}=0$ as well.

###### Part (c)

We have already shown that $\{\text{id},\dots,\sigma^{n-1}\}$ is $F$-linearly independent.
It remains to show that the set spans $K$.
This is equivalent to proving that $K$, when viewed as an $F[X]$-module via $\sigma$, is a cyclic module.

Hint:

> Use (or prove) that if the minimal polynomial of $\sigma$ equals the characteristic polynomial of $\sigma$,
>  then the list of invariant factors has length $1$.

Solution:

> Note that $\sigma^n-\text{id}=0$, so $X^n-1$ is divisible by the minimal polynomial of $\sigma$,
>  but by part (b), no polynomial with degree less than $n$ can annihilate all of $K$,
>  so the minimal polynomial is $X^n-1$.
>  Now, the characteristic polynomial is divisible by $X^n-1$
>  and has degree $[K:F]=n$,
>  so the characteristic polynomial equals the minimal polynomial.
>
>  Since the characteristic polynomial is the product of all invariant factors,
>  and the minimal polynomial is the largest invariant factor,
>  the only possibility is that there is only one invariant factor,
>  which shows that $K$ is a cyclic module.